# Condicionales anidadas en Python

Tags: python

Me genera un error en los dos puntos del primer if y en los parentesis del ultimo print

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La indentacion de los `else` no es correcta

Comment: Además procura mostrar el código como texto, las imágenes no son bien recibidas, lee [ask]

Comment: Gracias, ya se para la próxima vez.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Answer (score 2):

La causa del error era que faltaba por cerrar un paréntesis al principio, en la lectura de la nota. Un paréntesis sin cerrar en una línea puede causar errores que Python puede tardar más líneas en detectar. Además cada `else` debe estar alineado con su correspondiente `if`, en lugar de como lo has puesto alineado con el `print`.

Al margen de eso, hay algunos aspectos que pueden hacer tu código más *pythónico* y sobre todo **más legible**.

- En python las condiciones no necesitan paréntesis alrededor
- Python admite comparaciones "múltiples", que tienen este aspecto `51 < nota <= 65` y que el intérprete ejecuta como equivalente a `51 < nota and nota <= 65`.
- En python tienes la construcción `elif` que equivale a un `else` seguido de un `if`. Esto ayuda a reducir la indentación del código lo que redunda en una gran mejora de la legibilidad.

Con estas observaciones tu código se vería así:

```py
print("Bienvenido")
nota = int(input("introduzca la nota obtenida"))
if 0 < nota <= 50:
    print("Usted ha suspendido")
elif 51 < nota <= 65:
    print("Usted ha aprobado")
elif 66 < nota <= 85:
    print("Usted es un estudiante notable")
elif 86 < nota <= 100:
    print("Usted es un estudiante sobresaliente")
elif 100 < nota:
    print("Estudiante con matrícula de honor")
```

**Nota:** aún podría ponerse al final del todo un `else` para cubrir el caso en que la nota no entre por ninguno de los anteriores, e imprimir en ese caso "Usted es un estudiante muy negativo" :-)

Comment: Por otro lado creo que las condiciones están mal, aunque me he limitado a copiar las que tú usabas. Un 50 no debería ser un aprobado? Y puede alguien sacar más de 100? Creo que el `<=` debería ser el primero y el `<` el segundo, como por ejemplo `0 <= nota < 50`, y después `50 <= nota < 65`,  etc.

Comment: Esta respuesta me parece correcta, la sentencia elif esta diseñado para crear listas de condicionales o condicional múltiple si quieren llamarlo así.